# Pipeline to remove None values

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

My spider yields certain data but sometimes it doesn't find the data.
Instead of setting a condition such as below:

```
if response.xpath('//div[@id="mitten"]//h1/text()').extract_first():
    result['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="mitten"]//h1/text()').extract_first()
```

I'd rather fix this in my pipeline by removing all items that have a `None` value. I've tried to do this by the following code:

```
class BasicPipeline(object):
    """ Basic pipeline for scrapers """

    def __init__(self):
        self.seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item = dict((k,v) for k,v in item.iteritems() if v is not None)

        item['date'] = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
        for key, value in item.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value, basestring):
                item[key] = value.strip() # strip every value of the item

        # If an address is a list, convert it to a string
        if "address" in item:
            if isinstance(item['address'], list): # check if address is a list
                item['address'] = u", ".join(line.strip() for line in item['address'] if len(line.strip()) > 0)

        # Determine the currency of the price if possible
        if "price" in item:
            if u'€' in item['price'] or 'EUR' in item['price']:
                item['currency'] = 'EUR'
            elif u'$' in result['price'] or 'USD' in item['price']:
                item['currency'] = 'USD'

        # Extract e-mails from text
        if "email" in item:
            if isinstance(item['email'], list): # check if email is a list
                item['email'] = u" ".join(line.strip() for line in item['email']) # convert to a string
            regex = r"[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+"
            item['email'] = u";".join(line.strip() for line in re.findall(regex, item['email']))
            if "mailto:" in item['email']:
                item['email'] = item.replace("mailto:","")

        if "phone" in item or "email" in item:
            return item
        else:
            DropItem("No contact details: %s" %item)
```

However, this results in an error:

```
2018-03-05 10:11:03 [scrapy] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.item_scraped of <scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter object at 0x103c14dd0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/casper/Documents/crawling/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/casper/Documents/crawling/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/xlib/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 57, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/Users/casper/Documents/crawling/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 193, in item_scraped
    slot.exporter.export_item(item)
  File "/Users/casper/Documents/crawling/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/exporters.py", line 184, in export_item
    self._write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export(item)
  File "/Users/casper/Documents/crawling/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/exporters.py", line 199, in _write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export
    self.fields_to_export = list(item.fields.keys())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

I think it has to do with the fact that a field has been yielded to the pipeline but not returned at the end but that's just a guess.

Currently the pipeline has statements such as:

```
if "website" in item:
    # Do stuff
```

And I'd like to prevent adding unnecessary extra statements to check if the value is `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code would probably work if you returned the created item:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    item = dict((k,v) for k,v in item.iteritems() if v is not None)
    return item
```

That said, I would strongly recommend using [item loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) in your scrapy spiders.
Fields not being created for empty data is just one of the many benefits.

EDIT:

Now that you've included the full pipeline code, I can see that the error is on the very last line.
Your code creates an exception object, discards it, and returns `None`; the `DropItem` exception must be raised:

```
raise DropItem("No contact details: %s" % item)
```

Comment: Had that one coming. My `def process_item` continued after the first line so I am already returning it. (updated the question to reflect this)

Comment: Well, a `None` is still somehow finding its way to the item exporter. Hard to say exactly why without seeing all relevant code.

Comment: Full pipeline now added to the question.

Comment: Updated the answer.